# Prefix best match MySQL

Tags: mysql, string-matching, prefix

That's my scenario.
I have 4 tables: records, providers, routing_domain, domains.

- domains: id, name (something like 'example.com')
- providers: id, name (something like 'TLC')
- records: phone_number (varchar), provider_id (foreign key to
  providers)
- routing_domain: provider_id (foreign key to providers), domain_id
  (foreign key to domains) and prefix (varchar).

Example of tables:

```
mysql> select id,name from domains;
+----+-----------------------+
| id | name                  |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | e164.arpa             |
|  3 | example.com           |
|  0 | localhost.localdomain |
|  4 | luigi.it              |
|  2 | tim.it                |
+----+-----------------------+

mysql> select id,name from providers where id in (9,10);
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  9 | TIM      |
| 10 | VODAFONE |
+----+----------+    

mysql> select * from routing_domain;
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+
| id | prefix | domain_id | provider_id |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+
|  3 | 3932   |         4 |           9 |
|  1 | 39320  |         2 |           9 |
|  2 | 39321  |         3 |          10 |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

Now,

- given a phone_number '39320xxxxxxx' with provider_id 9, i need to get
  domain_id=2;
- given a phone_number '39321xxxxxxx' with provider_id 9, i need to get
  domain_id=4;

So, given a certain phone_number '3932xxxxxxxx' with provider_id=9, i need to do some bestmatch searching. Starting to search prefix with 6 chars, if not match, try with 5 chars and so on, until 3 chars (393).

I managed to get the correct domain from phone_number searching only from a prefix to 5 chars.

Something like:

```
select * FROM records r
left join routing_domain rd on rd.prefix like SUBSTRING(r.phone_number,1,5) and r.provider_id = rd.provider_id 
left join providers p on p.id = rd.provider_id
left join domains d on d.id = rd.domain_id 
where r.name = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Any advices to do this bestmatch ?
Thank you so much!

> Update

I tried with this:

```
select * FROM records r
left join routing_domain rd on on r.phone_number like concat(rd.prefix, '%') and r.provider_id = rd.provider_id 
left join providers p on p.id = rd.provider_id
left join domains d on d.id = rd.domain_id 
where r.name = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Now, if i search for '39325xxxxxxx', there is a match with prefix '3932',
but if i search for '39320xxxxxxx', both prefixes will match and the search returns 2 rows.

Comment: max prefix length is 5 digits?

Comment: Max prefix lenght is 6char (included international prefix, so '39xxxx'), min is 3 (39x)

Comment: your requirements are not complete. but you can start from something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e36df/7

Comment: what requirement is missing?

Comment: you have 2 records:  3932, 39320 in routing_domain table with same provider_id - which one should be returned when number is `393xxxxx..`? and why?

Comment: the best match. it means that if the number is not '39320x...' and not '3932x...', there is not match and so it return no prefix. In case of number is '39320x...' 
 it match with 39320, if number is '3932[1-9]' it match with 3932, an so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have a sub-query that gives you the longest prefix matching `provider_id` and `prefix`. Something like this:

```
select domain_id from routing_domain
where
  provider_id = 9
  and '39321xxxxxxx' like concat(prefix, '%')
  and length(prefix) =
  (    select max(length(prefix))
       from routing_domain
       where 
         provider_id = 9
         and '39321xxxxxxx' like concat(prefix, '%')
  )
```

See my fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7c830/10/0).

Comment: It seems work! I'll do more tests to make sure that will work with "no phone number" records. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e36df/10

```
SELECT r.*, 
       MAX(IF(rd.prefix = LEFT(r.phone_number,5),rd.prefix,
             IF(rd.prefix = LEFT(r.phone_number,4),rd.prefix,
                IF(rd.prefix = LEFT(r.phone_number,3),rd.prefix,''))))
FROM records r
LEFT JOIN routing_domain rd
ON r.provider_id = rd.provider_id
GROUP BY r.id
```

And to make it closer to your attempt:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e36df/17

```
SELECT t.*, p.*, d.*
FROM (
  SELECT r.*, 
         MAX(IF(rd.prefix = LEFT(r.phone_number,5),rd.id,
               IF(rd.prefix = LEFT(r.phone_number,4),rd.id,
                  IF(rd.prefix = LEFT(r.phone_number,3),rd.id,'')))) as rd_id
  FROM records r
  LEFT JOIN routing_domain rd
  ON r.provider_id = rd.provider_id
  #WHERE r.phone_number = '393xxxxxxxxxx'
  GROUP BY r.id
  ) t
LEFT JOIN routing_domain rd
ON t.rd_id = rd.id
LEFT JOIN providers p 
ON p.id = rd.provider_id
LEFT JOIN domains d 
ON d.id = rd.domain_id
```

Comment: Lets wait for your next question to appear one day... ;-) Good luck with your project anyway